# How to click to an html element in WebBrowser. (Without ID, etc.)

Tags: html, vb.net

My program have to click to html element (button), but it does not succeed..

The HTML element is:

```
<button class="btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes" aria-label'jóváhagy'="">Jóváhagy</button>
```

I have tried these metods:

1.

```
Dim buttons As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each button As HtmlElement In buttons
        If button.GetAttribute("class") = "btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes" Then
            button.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

2.

```
Dim buttons As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each button As HtmlElement In buttons
        If button.GetAttribute("aria-label'jóváhagy'") = "Jóváhagyás" Then
            button.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

3.

```
 Dim buttons As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each button As HtmlElement In buttons
        If button.GetAttribute("class") = "btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes" Then
            button.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

But none of them work. 
And also, i have read a lot of same question on the site, but i didnt found nothing, what could help me. I have no more ideas.
Someone knows the solution? Im using vb 2013, and default webbrowser(IE) in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of checking a HTML element's `class` attribute is actually to specify `className` rather than `class`.

Your first code should work if you fix this:

```
If button.GetAttribute("className") = "btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes" Then
```

Comment: @Vlagyimir : Glad I could help! Good luck!